# JIRA Python API return objects

Tags: python, python-jira

The following code is not working for me. I returns an object, but then I cannot query the fields of the object, or the object is the wrong object type. Any suggestions would be appreciated. Environment : Anaconda Python, JIRA Cloud.

```py
from jira.client import JIRA
import traceback

print("Start")
issue=None

def tryJIRAConnect(issue):
    jira_options = {'server': 'https://xxx.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/serverInfo?'}
    try:
        jira = JIRA(options=jira_options,  basic_auth=('xxx.xxx@xxx.com', 'xxxxxxxxxx'))
        issue=jira.issue('xxxDEV-1')
        print(f'Success : JIRA Issue is : {issue}')
        return(issue)
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        traceback.print_exc()
    
x = tryJIRAConnect(issue)
print(f'x is : {type(x)}')

try:
    print(x.raw)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    traceback.print_exc()
```

It returns

```
Success : JIRA Issue is : <JIRA Issue at 2460259479664>
x is : <class 'jira.resources.Issue'>
{'baseUrl': 'https://xxx.atlassian.net', 'version': '1001.0.0-SNAPSHOT', 'versionNumbers': [1001, 0, 0], 'deploymentType': 'Cloud', 'buildNumber': 100187, 'buildDate': '2022-01-05T14:01:29.000+0100', 'serverTime': '2022-01-08T12:33:41.914+0100', 'scmInfo': '07b4f58ec2724461528057c7cbdf73a2f653f223', 'serverTitle': 'Jira', 'defaultLocale': {'locale': 'en_US'}}
```

Comment: What exactly isn't working? It does not look like you are actually trying to query the Issue object.

Comment: Hi, I would think print(x.raw) would produce the content of the jira story, I have in the past tried to use x.fields() but error says its not a subsriptable type.  I would be happy to see the Key and Summary fields somewhere, just to know I have the issue object being returned.

Comment: What about for example `print(x.fields.project.key)`? See https://github.com/pycontribs/jira#quickstart

Comment: Was advised on the atlassian board by Pramodh M to change the url to stop at .net - which resolved the problem. He also referred me to a different atlassian library https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html which also worked within 5 minutes of changing my code.  It also seems to be much better documented than the previous library.

Comment: your suggestion works when I have the new URL in place also.  print(x.fields.project.key)

Comment: I have worked a little with https://github.com/pycontribs/jira (which seems to be an active project; last commit was on Nov 29, 2021). I was not aware of https://atlassian-python-api.readthedocs.io/index.html.

Comment: Its seems pretty good, but it does not give REST interface, more jql based. So trying to get a sprint report from JIRA is only via REST to my knowledge